# Calling a webservice twice from a mobile application .NET causing problems

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile

I have a mobile application calling a webservice. When I run the application once it works normally, but if i call it again without restarting the application, the webservice is not even triggered.

Do you have an idea of what the problem might be?

Comment: What kind of web service? WCF or ASMX? The problem is clearly your program or your service.

Comment: Is the mobile app based on .NET CF?

Comment: What does your calling code look like?

Comment: @John - ASMX
@Dave - Yes
@Nate - result = WebService_Online.ProcessCapturedImage(ImageByte);

Comment: If you call this web service from a web page, does it work the second time?

Comment: @Mark - I have a windows application having exactly the same code ... but it works everytime.

Answer (score 1):

A webservice call is essenially, reading a webpage.  So, the real question is -- "Is the GET request coming in?"  If so, the problem is with your server; if not, it's with the client.

Comment: how i can check this? for the time being, when the webservice is being triggered i am writing the time in a text file. I noted that at the second attempt no time is being written, which means that the webservice is not being triggered.

Comment: Use Fiddler (www.fiddler2.com) or WireShark (www.wireshark.org) to see the network traffic.

Comment: @mouth: Do you have that part of the code wrapped in a try block?  Sounds like an exception to me...

Comment: @James: a SOAP call is a POST not a GET

Comment: @mouth: If your second network call always fails, something is not being released.  Are you closing the network connection after the first successful call?

Comment: @Dave: I am using the <webservice>.Dispose() method. Is there any other way to release the network connection?

Comment: @John:  Oops... I was confusing SOAP & REST.  Regardless, I meant it in the sense of "the HTTP request".

Comment: @James: even REST uses more then just the GET request. It's all about HTTP.

Answer (score 0):

When First time web method is called, It is taken time for generation a proxy for web service.

Later it is saved into the cache. Best approach is to call a dummy or helloworld web method for generating proxy and saving into cache.

Next time, whenever any web method will be called, it will be performed quicker.